# cakephp mysql error

Tags: mysql, database, cakephp

I'm having some trouble with my site. What I want this view to do is display all invoices that relates to a userid(in another table), Instead the code is printing out all the invoices in the one view(disregarding the user id). When looking at the sql statement that cakephp debug spits out it shows the where as a blank(don't worry I'll include the actual sql statment). I also have session code created but I am unsure how to code it so that the mysql data will say where userid = current user;

here is the code for the view

```
<table width="100%" border="1">

            <table width="100%" border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>Biller</th>
                    <th>Subject</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
                <?php foreach($invoices as $invoice):?>
                    <tr> debug($invoices);
                        <td align='center'><?php echo $this->Html->link($invoice['Invoice']['biller'], 
                        array('action' => 'viewinvoice', $invoice['Invoice']['id'])); ;?> </td>
                        <td align='center'><?php echo $invoice['Invoice']['subject']; ?></td>
                        <td align='center'><?php echo $invoice['Invoice']['datecreated']; ?></td>
                        <td align='center'><a href="viewinvoice"><button>View Invoice</button></a><a href="disputeinvoice"><button>Dispute Invoice</button></a></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>

            </table>
```

here is the code in the class relating to this view

```
 public function payinvoice($id = null){
        $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Pay Invoice');
        $this->set('stylesheet_used', 'homestyle');
        $this->set('image_used', 'eBOXLogoHome.jpg');   
        $this->layout='home_layout';

        $this->set('invoices', $this->Invoice->find('all' , array('conditions' => array('Invoice.biller' => $id)))); 
}
```

and here is the sql code that site is using to retrieve the data

```
   SELECT `Invoice`.`id`, `Invoice`.`to`, `Invoice`.`biller`, `Invoice`.`subject`, `Invoice`.`description`, `Invoice`.`amount`, `Invoice`.`datecreated`, `Invoice`.`duedate` FROM `pra_cake`.`invoices` AS `Invoice` WHERE `Invoice`.`biller` IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are not passing an id into your page. The url should look like:

```
/invoices/payinvoice/2
```

Comment: how would one be able to achieve that?

Comment: See Moyed Ansari's answer above

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the issue of the url

try this

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('Invoice',
    array('controller' => 'invoices', 
          'action' => 'payinvoice', 
          $invoice['Invoice']['id'])
    );?>
```

it will generate

```
<a href="/invoices/payinvoice/6">Invoice</a>
```

Comment: it comes up with a link on the site but its only 'invoices/payinvoice/'

Comment: Can you post the code you use to populate $invoice and the output of debug[$invoice] please?